# Alternatives to Download Helper?

Tags: windows, video, firefox, download-manager

I am regularily using [Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) to download video, to watch them later when in transit. The best part of this plugin is that it reliably detect any video or audio on the page, and allow the downloading of it.

But I am now searching for a alternative, because they are pushing harder and harder to install their "ConvertHelper" (FFMpeg rebranded), which I don't trust at all, is now "neccessary" to download video that were easily downloadable without some month ago, and is a paying, closed source product. *(And let's not talk about the ethics of selling a open source product)*

I know there is a lot of "Youtube downloader" addons for firefox, but I also grab video that are on independent site, and as such need the plugin to detect automatically the source.

A Firefox add on is prefered, but I am open to reputable / open source executable on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same thoughts quite a while ago...

i "switched" to [**FlashGot**](https://flashgot.net/) because i used it anyway from time to time for mass downloading and integration with my external download manager:
it is not perfect but detects videos pretty well and is better than most of the other "special" addons. further it is free AND open source software from the same developers of NoScript... so no nasty additional software/downloader/converter or advertisement.

**Edit 2018-11-14:**

Unfortunately, FlashGot [isn't compatible with Firefox Quantum](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/).

---

if you want a external tool [youtube-dl](http://youtube-dl.org/) or on it based tools/GUIs are the way to go...
it is a command-line program written in python - therefore platform independent, free and open source.

Comment: FlashGot is really good, and also find HD video when download helper "couldn't" detect them. Also can download multiples media by pages, awesome recommendation :)